# Sitecore.Context.Item returning obsolete data that doesn't match what's in the web database

Tags: caching, context

I have an odd issue that seems to be related to caching but I've never seen this before.

`Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["OfficeContacts"].Value` is returning a different value from `Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Sitecore.Context.Item.ID).Fields["OfficeContacts"].Value`

We're frequently getting the wrong content on the site- after content editors publish changes, they do not show up in SOME user sessions but show up correctly in other sessions. It seems random. I've gotten the obsolete data in an incognito session, and the updated data in my regular Chrome session. Seems to have nothing to do with whether the user has visited the site before, as colleagues who have never been to the site saw the old content when testing. This is reproducable on lower environments.

When reproducing the issue on my local, my debugging revealed `Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["OfficeContacts"].Value` returned the obsolete value, which DOES NOT match what is visible in the web database raw values. However, `Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Sitecore.Context.Item.ID).Fields["OfficeContacts"].Value`, in the same session and same Watch window, DOES return the correct data.

What would cause `Sitecore.Context.Item` to cache or return old data?

Comment: Separate CD CM, one CD

Comment: When you say obsolete value, do you mean a previous value that was assigned to item? Or a value from a different item than expected?

Comment: The former, the previous value before publishing

Comment: When you check this item in the `web` database, how many item versions are shown in the versions dropdown? If you see more than one, it can be caused by content testing.

Comment: What is your setting for `eventQueueProvider`? Is it `eventQueueProvider defaultEventQueue="web"`? And what about `<setting name="EnableEventQueues"`?

Comment: Is it possible that you are using the more recent of partial cache clearing option? (i.e. PartialHtmlCacheClearer -https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/sitecore-experience-manager/configure-html-caching.html). If so, then I suspect that cache is not correctly being cleared on update. Sitecore.Context.Item always comes from cache, whereas Database.GetItem() always comes from database. So if cache not correct you will see a difference.

Comment: @DeanOBrien that would make the most sense. thanks, I'll look into that!